# Excel - How to keep top row fixed while scrolling left to right

Tags: excel

Basically, I have a sheet which has a summary in the top row, but the data entry extends past the right side of the visible window. I'd like to keep the summary in place while being able to scroll right to edit data entry. I hope this picture explains it a bit better.
[image]

I have a feeling its probably not possible, but i figured if someone can build flappy bird inside of excel then surely theres a chance this can work :D

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Use the [Camera Tool](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-use-camera-function-in-microsoft-excel/44a97349-f694-4bd3-a5ca-e4097f6e9437)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think this will be the solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: open a mirror window (just a second view of the same sheet), and leave it scrolled to your summary data while you work in the other window.

You can keep some amount of rows on the left from scrolling, under the freeze options:

Select AA5 in your example. Then View --> Freeze Panes --> Freeze Panes.

This will force rows above your cell to stay at the top when you scroll down, and columns to the left of your cell to stay visible when you scroll the screen right. However, Column AA is probably going to be hard to fit onto the screen and still show much editing room to the right. This works best when you only need to hold a few summary cells visible.

The other approach would be refactoring -- Make the weeks rows and the tasks columns. Excel generally works best with more columns than rows, and this is probably the better long term approach.

Edit: a third approach, but more intensive -- if you create the summary elements inside graphic containers, I believe you can make them 'float' on the page via some scripting (ie, adjust their position everytime you scroll).

Failing that ... more monitors!

Comment: Thanks Halbert, I know about freezing panes, and I don't want to redesign the sheet. I had thought about writing a macro for it using ActiveX controls, but I don't need the lead row to stay still THAT bad lol

Comment: Actually, I had a thought: open a mirror window. Probably one on top, one on bottom for your design. One example here, but simple idea. https://marqueegroup.ca/resource/excel-efficiency-working-simultaneously-in-multiple-parts-of-the-same-workbook/#:~:text=Step%201%20%E2%80%93%20Create%20a%20Mirror,the%20file%2C%20as%20shown%20below.